# Добавление элементов списка в ячейку DataFrame, где находится список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

Мне необходимо множество list добавить в ячейку DataFrame без перебора всех значений list. Добавить в ячейку присваиванием.

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,'r',['a','b','c'],[]]])
N = ['1','2','3','4','5']
df.loc[0,2].append('u')

df.loc[0,2].append(n)
```

Код должен к ['a','b','c'] добавить list `N = ['1','2','3','4','5']` вот так `['a','b','c','u','1','2','3','4','5']`. А у меня получается `[a, b, c, u, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`

Спасибо!

Comment: Замечания: `list` - это список, а не множество и у вас нет описания переменной `n`, зато есть `N`, это не одно и то же для питона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вопрос на азы питона, к `Pandas DataFrame` вопрос на самом деле отношения не имеет. Нужно использовать метод списка `extend`, а не `append`:

```
df.loc[0,2].extend(n)
```

Содержимое `df` после этого:

```
    0   1   2                           3
0   1   r   [a, b, c, u, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] []
```

`append` добавляет к списку свой аргумент как единое целое, а вот `extend` итерируется по своему аргументу, добавляя к списку каждый элемент аргумента по отдельности.

Comment: Спасибо, работает